# Page in React renders before the clients permissions are checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have executed a query in Javascript to fetch the data of the current user in my application. This query returns the current user's (the clients) data which is used to check the clients access permissions for various pages in my React application using Apollo Client and GraphQL.

However, for a page that only the administrator should have access to, whilst this query is taking place the page renders so that a user without administrator permissions can temporarily view the contents of the page. Once the permissions have been checked and it is known that the user does not have access, an error page is produced.

I would like this error page to be produced immediately so that none of the content can be viewed at all by clients who don't have permission.

```
// This is a currentUser.js file that is imported by various React components 
// which uses the query to check permissions

import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export default apolloClient => apolloClient
    .query({
        query: gql`
            query CURRENT_USER {
                name
                age
                gender
                permissions
            }
        `,
    })
    .then(({ data }) => ({ currentUser: data }))
    .catch(() =>
        ({ currentUser: {} }));
```

```
// This is a AdministratorPage.jsx file that shouldn't render whilst 
// permissions are checked

import currentUser from '../lib/currentUser';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ApolloConsumer } from 'react-apollo';

class AdministratorPage extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ApolloConsumer>
                {(client) => {
                currentUser(client).then((data) => { ...}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The way I typically get around any amalgamation of this problem is by doing a check before the render, this also allows me to leverage off of `spinners/loading status bars`. Although, I usually keep my primary state to the highest possible component (up until just before unnecessary re-renders may occur). A ternary operator or a JSX condition `{true && (render)}` may assist you. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should render loading page or some sort of loading indicator until the current user data is fetched. Try something like this in your `render` method:

```
<Query query={GET_CURRENT_USER}>
  {({ data, loading, error }) => {
    if (loading) return <Loading />;
    if (error) return <p>ERROR</p>;

    return (
      <AdministratorPage />
    );
  }}
</Query>
```

Comment: The data of the currentUser query is fetched in the currentUser.js file rather than in the AdministratorPage.jsx file. Are you suggesting I instead fetch the data for the current user in the AdministratorPage.jsx using the above format? Is there not a way of putting the 'if (loading) return <Loading />;' condition in the currentUser.js file?

Comment: @LivStan currentUser.js is just a utility that makes a request. What you can do, is call the API in the componentDidMount, have loading, error and data in the internal component state for AdministratorPage, then do the rendering. render method should not have any async calls.

Comment: @LivStan have you managed to solve your issue? If so, I would appreciate if you accept the answer.